# How to get FindsBy attribute value programmatically in webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Let's we have the following button declared on the page:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "btnUserApply")]
public Button ApplyButton { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to get programmatically the web element locator Id value? Something like this:

```
string id = applyButton.GetLocatorValue(How how);
```

Or I should use reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

`string id = applyButton.GetAttribute("id");`

You can get every attribute, just write it's name instead of "id".

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to get Id value when you know it (you find element by id).

Comment: Actually webdriver cannot click on this element (not sure why). And I use ExecuteScript to click on it. So to not duplicate id value I'm going to use this: this.WebDriver.ExecuteScript(@"var element = document.getElementById(arguments[0]').click();", this.ApplyButton.GetAttribute("id"));

Comment: What do you mean 'webdriver cannot click'? Is there any exception? WebDriver can't find it or maybe 'element is not clickable at point'?

Comment: It throws 'does not contain a definition for click method'. It could find the element but could not click it.

Comment: Did you tried to change type from Button to IWebElement?

Comment: Yes. Actually it looks like a checkbox but internally it's a button.

Comment: But `Button` is not selenium webdriver type. You should use `IWebElement` for all elements, doesn't matter if it looks like checkbox or button or whatever.